# Явный вызов конструктора по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Что это такое? Может ли кто-нибудь привести пример? Решение через указатель не подходит.

Comment: Вопрос наверное не из вакуума возник. Добавьте контекста для прояснения сути.

Answer (score 2):

Формально, язык С++ вообще не предоставляет вам средств для явного вызова конструктора. Вызов конструктора - это всегда побочный эффект процесса *инициализации*. Вы, как пользователь, можете лишь инициировать процесс инициализации. Это процесс будет проходить по довольно разветвленной системе правил. И в каких-то ветках этой системы правил он может вылиться в вызов конструктора. А может и не вылиться. Управлять этим вы можете лишь косвенно - предоставляя в своем классе те или иные конструкторы и указывая тот или иной инициализатор. Средств прямого вызова конструктора в языке нет. Это относится ко всем конструкторам, в т.ч. к конструктору по умолчанию.

---

Наверное, единственный контекст, который можно назвать отдаленно приближающимся к "вызову конструктора" - это делегация из одного конструктора в другой в С++11... Однако нет: согласно спецификации языка, делегация конструкторов работает по общим правилам инициализации. Что, кстати, дает нам еще один баг GCC. Вот в таком коде

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
  int x;

  S() = default;
  S(const char *) : S() {}
};

int main() 
{
  S s("abba");
  std::cout << s.x << std::endl;
}
```

GCC не инициализирует `s.x` нулем. Clang и MSVC работают правильно. Смена инициализатора с `()` на `{}` приводит к инициализации нулем и в GCC тоже.

Comment: А почему он должен инициализировать `x`?

Comment: @ixSci: Инициализация при делегации проходит по общим правилам (http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#7). Инициализатор `()` должен вызывать *value-initialization* (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.4). А *value-initialization* для класса без user-provided конструктора по умолчанию должно приводить к zero-initialization (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8.2). Конструктор, который объявлен как `= default` не является user-provided (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#5)

Comment: Хм, а почему мы можем считать это инициализатором? Это делегация вызова конструктору по умолчанию. Я не могу найти где в стандарте одно увязано с другим.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну первая же ссылка в моем комментарии (http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#7) говорит, что инициализатор в делегации обрабатывается по общим правилам direct-initialization [dcl.init] в применении ко всему объекту. Уже тот факт, что там можно использовать `{}`-инициализаторы как бы намекает, что это не просто "вызов конструктора", а все таки более общий контекст, т.е. инициализация.

Comment: Ну, первая же ссылка в Вашем комментарии была совершенно другой, а этой там вообще не было ;) Спасибо, тем не менее.

Comment: @ixSci: Учитывая, что комментарии редактируемы только в течение очень ограниченного времени, претензии вроде "ссылка была совершенно другой" администрация принимать не будет :) Подождите пока аффтар перестанет метаться и остановится на финальной версии комментария. И не забудьте обновить страницу :)